# Struggling using Resolve in Angular 9

Tags: angular

I'm trying to use a resolver class in a component, but receiving the following error in the browser:

```
core.js:6237 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[QuoteResolver -> QuoteService -> QuoteService -> QuoteService]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for QuoteService!
```

in my main app-routing.module.ts I have included the resolver in the pat as follows:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'quotes/list', component: QuotesListComponent, resolve: {
        quoteListMeta: QuoteResolver
    }},
];
```

the component file (reduced to the main code concerning the issue):

```
export class QuotesListComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnInit {

    quoteListMeta: QuoteListMeta;

    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private quoteService: QuoteService) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.route.data.subscribe((data: { result: any }) => {
            console.log(data);
        });
    }

}
```

my service file is as follows:

```
@Injectable()

export class QuoteService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    }

    getQuotes(quoteId: number, filter = '', sortDirection = 'asc', pageIndex = 0, pageSize = 3) {
        return this.http.get(url, {
            params: new HttpParams()
                .set('action', 'list')
                .set('pageIndex', pageIndex.toString())
        }).pipe(
            map( res => res)
        );
    }

    getAll() {
        return this.http.get<Quote[]>(`${environment.apiUrl}/users`);
    }
}
```

and then finally the resolver class:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {ActivatedRouteSnapshot, Resolve, RouterStateSnapshot} from '@angular/router';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import { Quote } from '@app/models/quote';
import { QuoteService } from '@app/services/quote.service';
import { QuoteListMeta } from '@app/models/quote.list.meta';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})

export class QuoteResolver implements Resolve<any> {

    constructor(private quoteService: QuoteService) {
    }

    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
        console.log('resolve');
    }
}
```

It looks like it is not injecting the QuoteService class into the resolver.  I have had a look at several tutorials to aid me in implementing the resolver but I can't see what I'm doing wrong or missing.  Any help would be appreciated.

Musaffar

Comment: You can either add `QuoteService` to providers array of `@NgModule` or add `providedIn: 'root'` to it

Comment: Thanks!  I added QuoteService to @NgModule which did the trick, turned out to be something obvious which I missed and spent much time struggling with :)

Comment: What about `@Injectable({  providedIn: 'root'
})
`?